# remove battery or sim card in android

Tags: android, gps

Hi i have two questions about android apis:
I want to use android apis that when user remove the sim card or remove the battery application saves user actions on database.Can i do these problems in android os?
this applications is fleet management gps tracking  application.But i don't know how to cover these issues in android system.
Can i cover these issues in android device?
Or i need other hardware for fleet management system?

Comment: Removing the battery you say...no power = no power to run a app

Comment: SIM status change is notified to the Android RIL Java layer through an unsolicited callback from Vendor RIL. I'm not sure if you have a public API to access this state in the latest ICS release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use android apis that when user remove the sim card or remove the battery application saves user actions on database.Can i do these problems in android os?

Not really.

With respect to the SIM card, *changing* a SIM *may* result in a configuration change, if the MCC or MNC changed. Simply removing a SIM card does not raise an event available in the SDK, AFAICT.

With respect to the battery, odds are good that the device will be powered down when the battery is removed, either intentionally or unintentionally. Few Android devices support removing the battery while the device is powered on.

> this applications is fleet management gps tracking application

This does not have anything obvious to do with removing SIM cards or batteries.